# Identity Server 4 not setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for `.well-known/openid-configuration`

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, identityserver4

Builder for policy :

```
        private CorsPolicy GenerateCorsPolicy()
        {
            var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            return corsBuilder.Build();
        }
```

Adding policy to container

```
            services.AddCors(
                options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", GenerateCorsPolicy());
                });
```

Telling Identity Server to use this policy :

```
                        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                        options.Cors.CorsPolicyName = "AllowAllOrigins";
```

Configuring the rest of the app to use this policy too :

```
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(
                endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

Header is not set :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You control CORS in IdentityServer separately, using the AllowedCorsOrigins property in the Client defintions:

```
        AllowedCorsOrigins =
        {
            "https://localhost:5001"
        }
```

Your pipeline looks a bit odd as well:

```
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

I don't see any reason for adding middlewares after the UseEndpoints middleware in your case.

The pipeline looks like this and your incoming request progress through this pipeline and each middelware can take action on the request, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, so what's the point of having this `CorsPolicyName` settable if it has no efffect ? Your suggestion worked by the way, I just find it very weird...

Comment: Because you had UseCors last in the pipeline, then it would probably not get hit at all. you could always try to add it earlier in the pipeline. It can also be that IdentityServer would block CORS-requests entirely, because they would violate the CORS-URL in the client definition.

Comment: okay, then I guess I'm not understanding how to set up a pipeline correctly yet... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Added a picture (from one of my training classes) of how you can reason about the pipieline and each app.UseXXX() addes one item to this pipeline in sequential order.